# How to connect/communicate with Postres server using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, postgresql

In php I can connect to my Postgres server and query it like this:

```
<?php
    $string="host=localhost port=5432 user=me dbname=mydb";
    $conn=pg_connect($string);

    $x=pg_query($conn," SELECT * FROM users;");        
?>
```

Is there a similar way to do it in a .aspx file?

Comment: You say AJAX in the title and .aspx in the question.  Which is it?

Comment: @Adam Wait, can I just use the php file as the ajax url $.ajax({
             url: 'somephp.php'});

Comment: Yes, AJAX is just used to mean asynchronous calls to the server using javascript (i.e. without reloading the page).  Some server-side code then returns a result which the javascript presents or uses in some way. You can use any server-side technology to respond to the AJACX call.  PHP and ASP.NET (which is what an .aspx file is) are alternative server-side techinlogies.